# php,sql - how to alter values from one column and inserting it into other

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna get the values from a column `column1` and delete all the 
*(spaces , %20, %2520, _ (underscore), - (hyphen) and . (dot))* from it and save the values to the corresponding place in other `column2`.
Is this the right way to do it? will this even work?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

$sql= "SELECT column1 FROM table" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


    $x= $row["column1"] ;


$find=array(" ","%20","%2520",".","-","_");
$x= str_replace($find,'',$x);


               $sql2 ="INSERT INTO table
             ( column2 )
             VALUES
             ( '$x' )";

              if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
               echo "Record Created <br>";

                }

              else {
               echo "Error creating Record: " . $conn->error;
               }

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: `Mysql` <> `SQL Server` choose the one you are using

Comment: You tell us: Does it work? And if not, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: i am using `mysql` @Prdp

Comment: i can't risk my database @jeroen

Comment: So you didn't even tried this?

Comment: Really? You are going to make untested changes to your live database based on what someone tells you here???

Comment: i want them to enter in the corresponding row as of the value of column1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Step

`UPDATE table SET column1 = column2`

Second Step

`UPDATE table SET column2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column2, ' ', '') , '%20', '') ,'%2520', ''), '.', '') , '-', '') , '_', '')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `Update` not `Insert`.

Use `REPLACE` function to remove the unwanted characters in your column

First run `select` and check whether everything is fine then run `update`

```
SELECT column1,
       Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(column1, ' ', ''), '%2520', ''), '%20', ''), '_', ''), '-', ''), '.', '') AS column2
FROM   yourtable 

UPDATE tablename
SET    column2 = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(column1, ' ', ''), '%2520', ''), '%20', ''), '_', ''), '-', ''), '.', '')
```

Comment: @Azhar - ofcource because you are running a update query. Even after that first run the `select` if the result is fine then run the update query

Comment: @Azhar what do you mean by not working add sample data and my query result

Comment: what if I UPDATE table
SET column1 = column2

Comment: and then Replace the string

Comment: @Azhar - Did the replace happened properly or not ?

Comment: I did it by my method, I posted the answer. By your way it just hanged and nothing happened btw there are 100,000 rows in my table